# In a series of prompts, need to keep asking the last prompt over and over until answer

Tags: javascript, loops

I'm creating a joke script for a site that does a series of prompts asking the user if they agree I know javascript.   After they answer negative the first time, a slightly modified version of the question is restated.  And finally a mocking version of the question is asked and if answered negatively will just ask it again and again until it's answered yes.  I can get to the last part just fine.  But I can't figure out how to get the code to go back to the last question over and over again and then switch to "thank you" response after they finally are forced to say yes.  any help would be appreciated.

my code:

```
javascriptExample.addEventListener("click", function(){
    const answer = prompt("This prompt was created using Javascript. Are you now satisfied we know Javascript? Y/n: ");
    if (answer == "n") {
        answerTwo = prompt("Sigh.  Fine.  What about now?  Y/n: ");
        if (answerTwo = "n") {
            do{
             const answerThree = prompt("Look, I can do this all day long.  So, why don't you knock it off and just go ahead and say yes already, okay?  Y/n: ");
            } while(answerThree == "n");
        } else {
            alert("About time. Thank you for your cooperation and vote of confidence. I'm wasn't sure I could've kept it up forever.");
        }
    } else {
        alert("Thanks for the vote of confidence.  You're a real mensch!");
    }
});
```

Comment: Typo in `if (answerTwo = "n") {`. `=` is assignment, `==` and `===` are comparison

Comment: By the way, you can use `confirm("Message")` instead of `prompt` to get an OK/Cancel dialog

Comment: FYI Creating a prompt that cannot be cancelled in an obvious way is about as bad of a UI design than one could come up with.

Comment: @ScottMarcus It's intended to be a joke, not an effective UI

Comment: @j08691 the irony...

Comment: @qxz I understand what you are saying. What I am saying is that it is not a funny joke and will most likely result in frustrated users closing the browser because they don't know of any other way to make the prompts stop.

Comment: @SealHead1 Move the "About time" alert after the if/else statement (so it gets executed no matter what if the user said "n" the first time

Comment: @ScottMarcus, don't worry, after the third prompt or so, the browser will show a checkbox to block all further dialogues from this site. And I'd definitely check it ;) ... and then leave the site forever

Comment: @Thomas Well, Chrome will. Other browsers may not.

Comment: These are all great points. Yeah, it's a joke for a small segment of a site.  People looking at it would be familiar with such things and get the joke quickly.  You folks are awesome.

Answer (score 1):

```
while(["A","B","C"].every(el=>!confirm(el))){}
alert("Fine");
```

A,B and C are your questions. Just a bit shortified...

If you wanna keep your exact answer structure:

```
if(confirm("A") || confirm("B")){
   alert("nice of you!");
   return;
}
while(true){
 if(confirm("C")){
   alert("youve got it");
    return;
 }
}
```

Comment: This will loop back to the first two questions if you hit Cancel more than 3 times.

Answer (score 0):

Note that variables defined using an ES6 `const` or `let` are [block scoped rather than function scoped](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#Scoping_rules_2) like variables defined using `var`.

For this reason, **`answerThree` is no longer is scope** inside the `while` condition and the comparison fails.

---

Instead, define the variable before the loop:

```
let answerThree;
do {
    answerThree = prompt("Look, I can do this all day long.  So, why don't you knock it off and just go ahead and say yes already, okay?  Y/n: ");
} while (answerThree == "n");
```

This will lead to your desired result. Also note that you cannot reassign `const`s, which is why a `let` needs to be used here.

Comment: This was really helpful.   Thank you.  Is there a way to get an alternate final alert that says something snarky once the do/while loop terminates?  I tried that before, but I couldn't figure that part out. Thanks so much.

Comment: Sure, just put it right after the line with the `while`! It will be executed once the loop has finished, and only then.

Answer (score 0):

> switch to "thank you" response after they finally are forced to say yes

This does not seems like a great idea to me because people might feel annoyed and really want to skip this question!

> get the code to go back to the last question over and over again

However if you need to ask multiple questions in multiple patters than I would suggest to store questions in an array (a 2D might be more helpful)

```
var question = {
'1' : {
    '1' : 'joke1.1',
    '2' : 'joke1.2'
},
'2' : {
    '1' : 'joke2.1',
    '2' : 'joke2.2'
}
};
question_no=2;
question_version=1

if (answer == "n") {
   question_version++;
   prompt( question_no[question_no][question_version]+  Y/n: ");
}else{
   question_no++;
}
```